# Как открыть порт в настройках роутера Интеркросс ICxETH 5670 NE?

Tags: ip, роутер, порты

Что конкретно нужно написать в этих полях? По этому интерфейсу в гуглах ничего нет к сожалению. Подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description** - описание (дать название для удобства), например http;
**Remote Host** и **Remote Mask** - ip адрес хоста и маска удаленной сети. Если необходимо, что бы подключались множество клиентов с разных ip, то необходимо указать в Remote Host = 0.0.0.0 а в Remote Mask = 255.255.255.255 (однако уточните, нажав на кнопку со знаком вопроса);
**External Port** - внешний порт (который смотрит наружу), например 80 (это http);
**Internal port** - внутренний порт (на который транслируем входящие с внешнего порта данные), допустим 8080 (часто альтернативный http);
**Internal Client** - компьютер внутренней сети который будет получать данные снаружи.
В описанном примере мы получили:
*все данные ото всех источников (Remote Host и Remote Mask) попадающих на внешний порт 80 (External Port) направить на клиента внутренней сети (Internal Client) на порт 8080 (Internal port)...*
Надеюсь, описал достаточно понятно...

Comment: @Justicet Спасибо вам большое! Я вас люблю!)) Вместо 0.0.0.0 он принял пустую строку. Только вот сам себе я выходит не режиссер, подключение по новому статичному ip с компьютера на котором открыт порт не работает.

Comment: статичный ип, выделенный Вам провайдером - это ип внешнего порта (WAN) Вашего рутера, но никак не компьютера, который находится в Вашей личной сети, т.е. после рутера (если смотреть снаружи)

Comment: да, я имел в виду порт переброшенный на ип компьютера.

Comment: еще раз - пусть роутер перенаправляет данные с внешнего адреса (из интернета) на внутренний web-сервер. Web по умолчанию 80 порт, значит данные с ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:80 надо направить на 192.168.120.5:8080 (внутренний адрес нашего сервера и порт который он слушает), таким образом цепочка получается такая:  ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:80 - forward to - 192.168.120.5:8080  На сервере (Internal Client) должно быть все правильно настроено и работать.   Да, опишите что конкретно требуется - какие сервисы, порты и т.п.

Comment: все работает как нужно, по ип люди из сети подключаются, дело в том что самому по этому ип подключиться не получается, только по 192.168.1.100.

Comment: из внутренней сети и не получится подключиться к внешнему ип для проверки работоспособности. Нужно подключаться с других внешних адресов - например подрубить к какому-то компу телефон и через него выйти в нет, после чего и осуществить тестовое подключение.