# Открытие портов на роутере Интеркросс ICxETH5670NE

Tags: роутер, порты

В гугле ничего нет по интерфейсу этого роутера.
Я находил подобный вопрос с ответом ([Как открыть порт в настройках роутера Интеркросс ICxETH 5670 NE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/348702/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-icxeth-5670-ne)), но даже с тем ответом у меня ничего не получается. [image: Вот интерфейс]

Вот допустим, я хочу открыть порт для майнкрафта 25565. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

enable - включить
remotehost =any или 255.255.255.255
remotemask= any или 255.255.255.255

internal client=255.255.255.255

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m1vizw

Comment: @lordtimey сколько же людей пользуются лайтшотом. Вы вообще знаете, что это небезопасно? [Подробнее об этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdEok_CGvnA)

Answer (score 0):

может это поможет http://27sysday.ru/interesno/interkross
Включите UPNP пробуйте открыть порт самим приложением.

Comment: Всё равно не открывает